# For to create callback in function component useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

In class component we can to

```
this.setState({
  fieldValue: fieldVal,
  fieldDirection: FieldDirection,
  sort: Sort
}, ()=>{
  callback()
});

this.setState({
  fieldValue: fieldVal,
  fieldDirection: FieldDirection,
  sort: Sort,
  addition: additional
}, ()=>{
  callback1()
});
```

In function component how can we `useEffect` to call different function

```
const method1 = () => {
  setFieldValue(val.value)
  setFieldDirection(val.direction)
  setFieldSort(val.sort)
  callback() // field value is not update then callback is executed
}

const method2 = () => {
  setFieldValue(val.value)
  setFieldDirection(val.direction)
  setFieldSort(val.sort)
  setAddition(val.addition)
  callback1() // field value/direction.sort/additional is not update then callback is executed
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the `useEffect` hook with the states as dependencies?

Comment: In class component it's anti-pattern to use the `setState` callback to chain further callbacks. Just use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the state you update to issue further side-effects.

Comment: @DrewReese Can you provide some example

Comment: @RameshReddy Can you provide some example

Comment: `useEffect(callback1, [fieldValue, fieldDirection, fieldSort, addition]);`

Comment: @DrewReese How can we differentiate when to call callback1 or callback as fields are same for callback also callback1 has additional addition

Comment: Use more than 1 `useEffect` hook. You can use as many `useEffect` hooks as you've side-effects you want to run them for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using useEffect and state combination